# Power BI - 4 Week Increase / Decrease as a percentage

Tags: powerbi

I have a view that has the below fields:

[image]

In Power BI I need to display a card that shows a 4 week average as a percentage.

So the data above shows the total amount of emails sent per day, what I need to figure out is :
week 1 we sent 1000, week 2 we sent 1500 etc

So the percentage increase week on week is 50%.

I need to be able to calculate this increase/decrease as a percentage and show it on a card.

I have tried all of the quick measures and nothing seems to work, I have tried another example from the bi community here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-calculate-average-growth/td-p/289403

and that did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue with the approach in the linked thread? Does it give you an error? Does it calculate the wrong thing?

Comment: Yes it always comes back as an empty value e.g. blank

Comment: @NickODell so I have followed the thread again more carefully and I now have numbers coming back in, but I'm not convinced they are right, I'm the thread in the first instance the guy calculates a day on day growth, does that apply to me? Wouldn't I want week on week? How I have left it is I have followed the thread exactly and to get my 4 week average I have out a date filter on the card to say last 28 days, in principal does that seem correct?

Comment: I know very little about Power BI. I'm not totally sure their statistical method makes sense. E.g. Say you have 10 customers on even days of the month, and 20 customers on odd days of the month. You have growth of either 100% or -50%, for an average of 25% growth each day. Seems like a geometric average makes more sense here.